# Possible of error : Magento 2.0.4 to 2.1.0 Upgrade Check Component Dependency Error

Tags: magento2, component, magento-upgrade

From magento 2.0.4 to 2.1.0 Component Dependency Error, how can i solve below error,

[image]

Comment: Do you have terminal access

Comment: I am just trying with localhost.

Comment: How did you ever run composer if you don't have terminal? It's a requirement for running this update.

Comment: https://snag.gy/pqcPYr.jpg  this is how i run the command

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the contents of `vendor` and then in the terminal change into the root magento directory which should have `composer.json`.

Run `composer install`. If `composer install` fails, it will be because `composer.lock` is not up-to-date, so you should run `composer update`.

Comment: what i did was, just deleted all files form vendor, and run composer install, all files auto generated in vendor folder, after i try to upgrade i am getting same error what i was getting yesterday.

Comment: how have you attempted the initial upgrade - in the admin wizard or using the composer.json?

Comment: what do you get when you run `composer update`?

Comment: My composer.json file : https://justpaste.it/4lpku  highlight the line my change.

Comment: Is right what i did in composer.json file

Comment: If i run composer update i getting following response : https://snag.gy/puA4HE.jpg

Comment: It looks there like `module-wishlist-sample-data` is causing a problem. Try removing it either from the terminal or `composer.json` and re-running `composer update`.

Comment: @ol'bobdole after delete module-wishlist-sample-data from composer.json still not working.

Comment: @ol'bobdole If you have any idea about this error : https://snag.gy/IBvx1X.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is the module : `module-wishlist-sample-data`, you have two solutions :

1. You update the module.
2. You remove the module.

**Case 1 (update) :**

You run these commands:

- `composer update`, `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

**Case 2 (remove) :**

Uninstall module via composer :

- `php bin/magento module:uninstall -r <Vendor>_<Module>`, `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

Removing it manually :

> I do not recommend this way, you can use it just if the other
>   solutions really did not work or that you have removed the module not in the right way or you are stuck !

1. Remove the module from `vendor/{moduleName}`
2. Remove the whole line of module name in these files `vendor/composer/`:

   - `autoload_files.php`, `autoload_psr4.php`, `autoload_real.php`, `autoload_static.php`, `installed.json`
3. php bin/magento setup:upgrade

Comment: Partially working, how can i solve new issue : https://snag.gy/IBvx1X.jpg

Comment: Do a backup of all `var` folder content then try to remove all the content of this folder `var`

Comment: I did already, but no use, not working...

Comment: My magento ver : 2.0.0 and i am try to upgrade 2.1.7, Readiness check completed, still not upgrade. May i know possibilities of error.

Comment: Try with a command line : `composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.1.7 --no-update`

Comment: My response to tried above command: https://snag.gy/9qNdUz.jpg

Comment: did you enter the public and private keys ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76880/discussion-between-zus-and-prince).

Comment: Not working after created key : My key : https://snag.gy/uRryMx.jpg and the error is : https://snag.gy/zo8tPK.jpg

Comment: Please scan your website with this : `https://www.magereport.com/`

Comment: I am work with my localhost...